# Assignment of value to variable not working in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently writing a program that contains a two dimensional newton raphson sub. it starts like this:

```
Sub newton11()

Dim x As Double, z As Double, tolerance As Double
Dim error_x As Double, error_z As Double
Dim iteration As Integer

iteration = 0
tolerance = 0.05
x = Range("h19").value
z = Range("h20").value
```

however when I run the sub, it doesn't work. When I was debugging I noticed when I hovered over x it was assigned a value of -344 when Range("h19") is 53 and z was assigned -5.12 when Range("20") is 0.

does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Does your workbook have multiple sheets or do you have multiple workbooks open? What are the values of ActiveSheet.Name and ActiveWorkbook.Name at that point in the code? Do those values return the name of the workbook and spreadsheet tab you are trying to pull values from?

Answer (score 6):

Always define the sheet where you pull the data from. If you write:

```
x = Range("H19").Value
```

by default you're saying:

```
x = ActiveSheet.Range("H19").Value
```

which is probably containing the value `-344` while you were waiting for `53`. With this:

```
x = Sheets("myGoodSheet").Range("H13").Value
```

you're sure you're referencing to the proper one. And as Mark says in his comment, even better if you reference the correct workbook with `Workbooks(j)` just in front of the `Sheets` collection.

Comment: +1 for reinforcing in a full answer the importance of always explicitly naming the workbook and worksheet. Heck you can do it by creating Worksheet objects at the top of your code. Just make sure you do it. Seems to be a common issue. Creates nagging reliability issues in small code like this but exponentially more difficult issues (and hard to diagnose) when you expand to, for example, multiple code modules running from buttons across a multi-tab spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing isn't possible.

Instead of this:

```
x = Range("h19").value
z = Range("h20").value
```

Extract variables:

```
Dim xRange As Range, yRange As Range
Set xRange = Range("h19")
Set yRange = Range("h20")

x = xRange.Value
y = yRange.Value
```

Now place a breakpoint on the `x = xRange.Value` line, and use the *locals window* (from the `View` menu) to inspect the runtime value of `xRange` and `yRange` - then <kbd>F8</kbd> and inspect the runtime value of `x`: the two *are* the same.

See [@Matteo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29685851/1188513) for the *why*.

Comment: I implemented this but it is still coming up with the same error! when I hover over xRange.Value it says it is 53 but when I hover over x it is -345. There is only one sheet on this, but two modules.

Comment: @j_needs_help are you checking the value while the yellow line is on it, or after you've stepped to the next line?

Comment: @RubberDuck it is not the yellow line. It's pale yellow boxes when I hover over the variables. I've checked the following formula are working correctly